# FastReport Document Properties( Title, Topic, Version, Author) Setting

Tags: fastreport

I'm creating .pdf reports with c # in fastreport.Then I'm trying to set the document properties in the report. In FastReport, these properties have both set and get properties, but these features are not assigned to the report that I saved.

Before saving the report as .pdf, FastReport can open its own form and enter the relevant topic, title and author data here, but I do not want the user to enter this process every time. I want to set these properties programmatically with c #.

How can I do this?

```
   //c# codes
   public Report_Test() 
   {
   FastReport.Report report1 = new FastReport.Report();
   report1.ReportInfo.Author = "Test Test";
   report1.ReportInfo.Description = "TEST Report";
   report1.ReportInfo.Created = DateTime.Now;
   report1.ReportInfo.CreatorVersion = "1.1";
   report1.ReportInfo.Modified = DateTime.Now;
   report1.ReportInfo.Name = "1.1";
   report1.ReportInfo.Version = "1.1";
   /*
   I wrote other codes here ()
   */
   report1.RegisterData(dataSet11.Tables["Datas"], "Datas");
   report1.GetDataSource("Datas").Enabled = true;
   (report1.Report.FindObject("Data1") as FastReport.DataBand).DataSource = 
    report1.GetDataSource("Datas");
    report1.Show();
   }
```

Comment: Open any one .pdf. Then right-click and enter Document Properties. There is the explanation tab. I want to print the author, title, and other data with c #. The above code needs to do this, but the report doesn't write the data I set, it looks blank

Answer (score 0):

The `report1.ReportInfo.xxx` properties control the informational data within the FastReports object (and are saved in the *.FR3 file).  They are not written to the data in the PDF export.  For that, you need to access the `TfrxExportPDF` object being used. That object has properties  `Title, Author, Subject, Keywords, Creator, Producer`